# My android's app theme wont change

Tags: android

When I change my theme in Android Studio via the button in the design menu, it shows in the preview but when i run it it is always the Dark Material theme. I have tried changing it in the manifest file but I don't see it. Where else should I be looking?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Build> Clean Project
2. Build> Rebuild Project